# Custom WP-Query showing all posts in "content" page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type "event" with a date as custom `post_meta`. Using the template's built-in loop would be fine but I needed to sort by date, I created a custom query:

```
<?php // the query
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'event' ,
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'event_start_date',
                'type'      => 'DATE'
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page'    =>  20, 
        'order'             =>  'DESC'
        );

    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'event' ); ?>

            <?php the_post_navigation( array(
                'prev_text'                  => __( '<span class="nav-prev">Prev article: %title</span>' ),
                'next_text'                  => __( '<span class="nav-next">Next article: %title</span>' ),
                'in_same_term'               => true,
                'taxonomy'                   => __( 'category' ),
                'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Continue Reading' ),
            ) ); ?>

            <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

The problem I have is that while the "archive" page is now sorting by date, as expected, when I go to the single page by clicking one of the post's permalink, it shows the wrong post content and then other posts below it. It's as if it's executing the query in the content template.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different query arguments for pages. Try to use conditional tags https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Single_Post

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with these but I don't see how that would resolve my issue. Perhaps you could share your line of thinking?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use a custom query for a single page. Thus with conditional tags you will be able to execute WP_Query only on the  Archive page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your custom query to reset various global post variables.

In your case, you'd add `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` immediately after your custom loop (i.e. after the `endwhile` statement).

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it hasn't had any effect. I added code to my header and found that the "archive.php" template is being used and then it's calling the "single-event.php" template which now has it's own query. So I created an "archive-event.php" template but WP will not use this, I've even written a function called by a filter to force the use of the template but no luck. It's driving me insane!

Comment: Sounds frustrating...Is the code quoted in you question from your `archive-event.php`, and is that the whole template? If you add a blank `archive-event.php` does it get called?

Comment: If you're building a custom loop with `WP_Query()` it mught be better to put this loop in a custom page template (rather than an archive template). Or if you want to stick with the archive page, you could alter the (specific) loop to sort by date using 'pre_get_posts' action hook.

Comment: That is the portion of the template that should start the custom loop, I made a blank archive template and that isn't being used by WP either, only the standard `archive.php`. I'd prefer to keep this as "clean" as possible, do you have any idea why the `archive-event.php` template could be ignored by WP?

Comment: Could something be hooked to the 'archive_template' filter?

Comment: It's possible but not probable, I got to a stage where I just added an `if` condition, left the normal loop if `true` then created a new loop in the `else` and added an `if(is_archive())` condition in the `content-event.php` file. It's a hack that I'm not happy with but it's doing the job for now